# get serialized array of a form depending on inputs in recursive ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problems.
I have this code:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <input name="name" type="radio" />
    <select name="url" size="1"></select>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input name="name" type="radio" />
                <select name="url" size="1"></select>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <input name="name" type="radio" />
                            <select name="url" size="1"></select>

                        </li>
                    </ul>                    
            </li>
        </ul>        
</li>
<li>
        <input name="name" type="radio" />
        <select name="url" size="1"></select>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input name="name" type="radio" />
                    <select name="url" size="1"></select>                   
                </li>
            </ul>        
    </li>  
    <li>
        <input name="name" type="radio" />
        <select name="url" size="1"></select>

    </li>
```

i want a js code that add `data-id` in each `li` with sequence key and then output an array like this

```
arr = [
    0 => [
            [
                name => ''
                url => '',
                children => [
                    name => ''
                    url => '',
                    children => [
                        name => ''
                        url => '',
                        children => 
                    ] 
                ]
            ],
            [
                name => ''
                url => '',
                children => [
                    name => ''
                    url => '',
                    children => [
                        name => ''
                        url => '',
                        children => 
                    ] 
                ]
            ]            
    ]
]
```

and so on

Comment: _“i want a js code that […]”_ – well, then go write one.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What is exactly the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/corinis/jsForm or other http://knockoutjs.com/ .

Whatever you choose you will need to set the structure in your markup for those libraries to work

like

```
  <input name="children.name">
```

Wihtout any extra markup you will need to code the whole parsing from scratch - altough libraries like http://www.jquery.com might help a bit.